# How to only allow your website to enter Realtime Database in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database (Realtime Database) in firebase can be accessed by anyone, I want to allow my site to access it only, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240098/firebase-rules-allow-only-specific-url), I followed the steps in the question answer but it didn't work

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: I mean, I followed the instructions of the person who answered the question

Comment: You may be interested by the new [AppCheck](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) feature.

Comment: This has been covered a few times over the past, so I recommend checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+only+my+site As Renaud commented, App Check is closest to what you're asking and will give you broad protection against abuse. But for full security you'll still want to [implement security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) on top of that too.